# How can we make autocomplete=off for password input in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am completely new to *AngularJs*. I need to make `autocomplete=off` for a password input.

Is `autocomplete=off` the only way or do we have to do it in some different way in *AngularJs*?

Comment: As a user, please don't do this

Comment: If you are refering to the dropdown that occurs when you start typing in your password. That shouldn't be happening if you're using `type="password"` on your input. If your using a plain text input, thats really bad form...

Comment: @JimDeville some banking applications require to do so !

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't nothing to do with AngularJS at all, but simply html.

Regarding to your statement, password fields shouldn't be autocompleting if they are set to type `password`, otherwise if you want to set a specific field inside a form to autocomplete off you can do it setting that property to false like this `<input autocomplete="on|off">`.

This can be defined at form level or at input level. In a form it would be like this:

```
<form action="" autocomplete="on|off">
</form>
```

Also you can define it in a form level, and override the behavior for some specific inputs like this:

```
<form action="" name="myform" autocomplete="on">
    <input autocomplete="off" name="myInput" >
</form>
```

In the above code, in the form *myform* the `autocomplete` is on, it means all inputs (the one which allow it) will do autocomplete, but in the input *myInput* will not, since it overrides the form behavior.

More info can be found in [The HTML autocomplete attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient:

```
<input type="password" 
       autocomplete="off"
       placeholder="password"
       ng-model="vc.password">
```

I added the `autocomplete="off"` just for redundancy but it seems completely unnecessary.

jsbin - https://jsbin.com/bowuxopese/edit?html,js,output