# Angular 8 autofill suggestions on password field

Tags: angular, forms, browser

I have seen various questions around this on stackoverflow but none has a working solution.

Is there a working method to disable browser AUTO-FILL suggestions from poping up on fields?

```
    <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      formControlName="hkfj"
      autocomplete="new-password"
      type="password"
      placeholder="hkfj"
      required
    />
  </mat-form-field>
```

I've tried setting `autocomplete="new-password|off|false|randomName|no..."`
Also tried to put hidden fields but none worked.

As long as the field had the `type="password"` the browser suggested a password.

Comment: Does this work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42511953/5640649 ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the full code, but the input should have a _name_ or _id_ and be descendant of a `form`.

Comment: The problem might occur becuase you have already stored the password for your project in the google passwords, remove the password from google passwords and also  test with different browsers, if it happens only with the chrome, then possibly google is autofilling your content from the saved details, which might not happen with other users.

Answer (score 1):

For angular

`<input [(ngModal)]="password" name="password" [attr.type]="password.length < 1 ? 'text': 'password'" />`

Don't use input type attribute.

---

Input type matters. ***[password]***

Not only chrome all the browsers will suggest Password suggestion based on input type only

When it detects with `<input id="passId" type="password"/>`

### **It will work 100% and working perfectly for me **

*Its important to remove `type="password"`*